# false vs 0 while serving object in database Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
class BeautySalonCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_create :set_default_values

    protected

        def set_default_values
            self.available = false
        end
end
```

When I use Rails console and input 'BeautySalonCategory.create!(name: "Some name")' I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
```

But if I change 'self.available = false' to 'self.available = 0' then no errors won't appear. Why? Thanks.

Comment: What's the type of your `available` field? Is it a number?

Comment: No, It's boolean. Database type is SQLite

Comment: set_default_values must return true, because before_create must know when function end with success // sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

There's two things going on: Rails [expects your `before_create` handlers to return a non-`false` value when they successfully run](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution), and the result of an `a = b` statement in Ruby is `b`. So your `self.available = false` version returns `false`, indicating to Rails that the `before_create` failed. If you define your method like this, everything will be fine:

```
def set_default_values
  self.available = false
  true
end
```

(Props to maringan for spotting this in the comments.)

Comment: please don't post answers explained by users in the comments of the question.  it's the commenter's prerogative to explain the answer in more details.